# Unable to run the Numpy.nper function in JupyterLab

Tags: python, numpy

A hint that something was incorrect was when Jupyter does not show a signture for the numpy.nper function ("Signature: numpy.nper(*args, **kwds)")
I go ahead and fill the arguments with the variables but recieve the following error. I have made sure there are no spelling mistakes in the variable names or syntax errors so I don't know where the mistake is. Can someone please help?

"RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 period = numpy.nper(investment_rate, -annual_cash, 0, desired_cash)

~\OneDrive\Ani\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py in _expired(*args, **kwds)
275
276                 def _expired(*args, **kwds):
--> 277                     raise RuntimeError(msg)
278
279                 return _expired

RuntimeError: In accordance with NEP 32, the function nper was removed from NumPy version 1.20.  A replacement for this function is available in the numpy_financial library: https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial

Comment: Did you read the error message? It clearly says that the function was removed.

Answer (score 2):

`"RuntimeError: In accordance with NEP 32, the function nper was removed from NumPy version 1.20. A replacement for this function is available in the numpy_financial library: https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial"`

It says in the error traceback that the function `nper` is not available in NumPy version 1.20 which you are using. You have two alternatives:

1. Downgrade NumPy to version 1.19 or lower

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.0
```

And you should be able to continue without any changes in your code.

2. Install `numpy-financial` package

```
pip install numpy-financial
```

In your code:

```
import numpy_financial as npf

# Change your current code to this
period = npf.nper(investment_rate, -annual_cash, 0, desired_cash)
```